# system("history > wow.history") not editing my file

Tags: command-line, bash

my file is also in a forked child. If that helps. What im trying to do is have the system copy the history into the text file.Though everytime i execute it. The file is still empty. When i run system("history > wow.history") it just gives me sh: 1: history not found.

```
File *fp=fopen("wow.history","w+");
if(fp ==NULL)
printf("could not open the file specified")
exit(1);
else
system("history > wow.history");
```

Im trying to have it copy it into the file without have the user input anything.

Answer (score 1):

The "history" command is built into the shell you are using and is not an external executable.  Hence it cannot be exec'd by the system() call.